# How to convert deep query parameters into Perl data structure?

Tags: perl, datatables

I learn using [Datatables](http://datatables.net/) to draw dynamic tables on my site, using server-side data as source for tables. Datatables uses complicated parameters in queries, which I'd like to convert into proper Perl datastructure. So, query string like this (wrapped into lines for clarity):

```
columns[0][data]=status&
columns[0][name]=&
columns[0][searchable]=true&
columns[0][orderable]=true&
columns[0][search][value]=&
columns[0][search][regex]=false&
columns[1][data]=some&
columns[1][name]=&
columns[1][searchable]=true&
columns[1][orderable]=true&
columns[1][search][value]=&
columns[1][search][regex]=false&
columns[2][data]=title&
columns[2][name]=&
columns[2][searchable]=true&
columns[2][orderable]=true&
columns[2][search][value]=&
columns[2][search][regex]=false
```

would become like:

```
@columns = ( {
    data => 'status',
    name => '',
    searchable => 1,
    orderable => 1,
    search => {
      value => '',
      regex => 0,
    }
  },
  {
    data => 'true',
    name => '',
    searchable => 1,
    orderable => 1,
    search => {
      value => '',
      regex => 0,
    }
  },
  {
    data => 'title',
    name => '',
    searchable => 1,
    orderable => 1,
    search => {
      value => '',
      regex => 0,
    }
  },
);
```

What is the best way to achieve it?

EDIT.
Additionally, in this particular case I use `CGI.pm` to retrive query params, this gives me flat data structure.

Comment: There is already perl integration for datatables which could give you what you need https://datatables.net/development/server-side/perl_mvc

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCarryOn: AFAIU, this and [Perl Module Datatables](https://metacpan.org/pod/DataTables) are incompatible with Datatables new API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use Data::Diver 'DiveVal';

my @columns;
my %translate = ( 'true' => 1, 'false' => 0 );
for my $param ( $query->param() ) {
    if ( $param =~ /^columns/ ) {
        my $value = $query->param($param);
        DiveVal( \@columns, $param =~ /\[(.*?)\]/g )
            = $translate{$value} // $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: What construct this is, where you assign to the function call (`DiveVal() = ...`)?

Comment: @w.k: it's a little used feature called lvalue subs; the sub has to declare that it is allowed to be called that way.  it is particularly useful in cases like this where the sub is creating a new container that presumably is going to be assigned to.  There's an alternate DiveRef that isn't special that you'd call like `${ DiveRef( ... ) } = $value`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you pulled the params from the CGI object, then the following could work:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %params = (
    'columns[0][data]'          => 'status',
    'columns[0][name]'          => '',
    'columns[0][searchable]'    => 'true',
    'columns[0][orderable]'     => 'true',
    'columns[0][search][value]' => '',
    'columns[0][search][regex]' => 'false',
    'columns[1][data]'          => 'some',
    'columns[1][name]'          => '',
    'columns[1][searchable]'    => 'true',
    'columns[1][orderable]'     => 'true',
    'columns[1][search][value]' => '',
    'columns[1][search][regex]' => 'false',
    'columns[2][data]'          => 'title',
    'columns[2][name]'          => '',
    'columns[2][searchable]'    => 'true',
    'columns[2][orderable]'     => 'true',
    'columns[2][search][value]' => '',
    'columns[2][search][regex]' => 'false',
);

my @columns;
while (my ($key, $val) = each %params) {
    next if $key !~ /^columns/;
    my @keys = $key =~ /\[(.*?)\]/g;
    my $ref = $columns[shift @keys] ||= {};
    $ref = $ref->{shift @keys} ||= {} while @keys > 1;
    $ref->{$keys[0]} = $val;
}

use Data::Dump;
dd @columns;
```

Outputs:

```
(
  {
    data => "status",
    name => "",
    orderable => "true",
    search => { regex => "false", value => "" },
    searchable => "true",
  },
  {
    data => "some",
    name => "",
    orderable => "true",
    search => { regex => "false", value => "" },
    searchable => "true",
  },
  {
    data => "title",
    name => "",
    orderable => "true",
    search => { regex => "false", value => "" },
    searchable => "true",
  },
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my $qs="columns[0][data]=status&columns[0][name]=&columns[0][searchable]=true&columns[0][orderable]=true&columns[0][search][value]=&columns[0][search][regex]=false&columns[1][data]=some&columns[1][name]=&columns[1][searchable]=true&columns[1][orderable]=true&columns[1][search][value]=&columns[1][search][regex]=false&columns[2][data]=title&columns[2][name]=&columns[2][searchable]=true&columns[2][orderable]=true&columns[2][search][value]=&columns[2][search][regex]=false";

my @data=split ("&",$qs);

my @col;

for (@data) {
   my ($val)=/=(.*)$/;
   $_=~s/=.*//;
   my @b=split(/\[(.*?)\]/);
   my @c=@b[grep {$_% 2} 0..$#b];
   if (@c==2) {
      $col[$c[0]]->{$c[1]}=$val;
   } else {
      $col[$c[0]]->{$c[1]}{$c[2]}=$val;
   }
}
```

or using `eval` for a more general solution:

```
for (@data) {
   my ($val)=/=(.*)$/;
   $_=~s/=.*//;
   my @b=split(/\[(.*?)\]/);
   my @c=@b[grep {$_% 2} 0..$#b];
   my $cmd='$col[$c[0]]->';
   for my $i (1..$#c) {
      $cmd.='{$c['.$i.']}';
   }
   $cmd.='=$val';
   eval ($cmd);
}
```